# Is it possible to make pdf files content readable but uneditable and secure

Tags: php, pdf

Normally, pdf files can be edited by applications like Adobe Acrobat Writer. And when we open the pdf files in applications like adobe acrobat reader, we can select the contents. I need the codes that can create the pdf file and make it's content uneditable and users can't select the contents.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: What purpose would this serve? Also, when considering answers giving the built-in PDF password bit, you should know that PDF Passwords are completely moot. Basically, the PDF reader can choose to ignore the password field completely. It won't encrypt the document or any such thing. So while, this may prevent people using Adobe Reader from reading your PDF, others will still be able to read it, using `epdfview` for instance.

Comment: @Earlz I don't want the files to be password protected as users have the previlege to read the contents but they musn't be given the access to select the contents.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can render text and overlay an image. I am not sure whether this will work - viewer applications may allow the text to be selected.
2. If you render the text as watermark annotations, then that content will not be selectable.
3. You could encrypt the document and set an empty string as the user password but a full string as the owner password document. This will allow anyone to open the document without entering a password. To prevent content selection, you need to specify deny "content selection" user permission.

Our company Gnostice has [PDF components](http://www.gnostice.com) for Java, .NET, and Delphi/C++Builder platforms. All of them can render text and images, create watermark annotations, encrypt PDF document, and also specify usage permissions.

Comment: I want to manipulate the pdf file and it's properties dynamically exploiting the php codes only. Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: We do not have no PHP libraries for this purpose but there are some PDF solutions for PHP. Check the Related section on the right of this page. That question has been asked several times. I must warn you that web servers will kill PHP scripts that runs for too long - happens if you load big PDFs. Ideally, you should write a PHP script that interacts with a native service that does the actual PDF processing. This service could be written in Java, .NET or Delphi/C++Builder - depending on the type of server and OS.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. But i can't see any posts in related section on the right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pdf password secure http://luxsci.com/blog/how-secure-are-password-protected-files.html.

On development enviroment using php, i have no idea how to implement it, but it helps... i guess if you convert all your text to image, they never could copy that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to know about creating a PDF file using PHP dynamically. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Use-PHP-to-Create-Dynamic-pdf-Files/ In the properties, you can make it read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Save the PDF file as an image. Then create a PDF of that image. If the PDF is multiple pages, you may want to consider saving it in a multi-page image format such as a tiff. Otherwise  you will end up with 1 image per page if using say, the jpeg format and then have to combine them into one PDF Document. I do this with Services Agreements all the time.